# Recursive Level Order traversal

Tags: java, tree, binary-search, breadth-first-search

I have come up with this code to do level order traversal recursively for a binary search tree.

```
private void printLevelOrder_Recursive(Node root2) {
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    queue.add(root2);

    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    stack.add(root2);
    if(stack.isEmpty() == false) {

        Node node = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(node.data);

        stack.addAll(printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children(node.left, node.right));
    }

    while(stack.isEmpty() == false) {
        Node node = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(node.data);
    }
}

private Stack<Node> printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children(Node left, Node right) {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    if (left == null && right == null) {
        return stack;
    }

    Stack<Node> leftChildren = new Stack<Node>();
    Stack<Node> rightChildren = new Stack<Node>();
    if (left != null && (left.left != null || left.right != null)) {
        leftChildren = printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children(left.left, left.right);
    }
    if (right != null && (right.left != null || right.right != null)) {
        rightChildren = printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children(right.left, right.right);
    }

    if (rightChildren.isEmpty() == false) {
        stack.addAll(rightChildren);
    }
    if (leftChildren.isEmpty() == false) {
        stack.addAll(leftChildren);
    }
    if (right != null) {
        stack.add(right);
    }
    if (left != null) {
        stack.add(left);
    }
    return stack;
}
```

where `Node` is:

```
public class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node left;
    public Node right; 
}
```

I looked at various implementations, but I find mine much easier. Could you please chime in with your review and thoughts?

Comment: I assume this is java? I took the freedom to tag your question as such, if I am wrong.. please correct me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Incorrect level order traversal

The implementation is not correct.
It doesn't work for trees that are deeper than 3 levels.

The only reason it still works for 3 levels is that `printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children` looks ahead to its left-right children.

The reason why this just cannot work,
is that `printLevelOrder_Recursive_Children` will recurse deep to its children, breaking the level order.
There is nothing in your code to keep the traversal on a level,
there's nothing to prevent from going too deep in a branch.

To demonstrate the problem, consider this tree:

> ```
>         A
>       B   P
>    C        Q
> D
> ```

The correct level order traversal should be: A, B, P, C, Q, D

But your implementation gives: A, B, P, C, D, Q,

To play with this, I modified the definition of `Node` a little bit,
to make it work with `Character` data (or any other type too):

```
static class Node<T> {
    public T data;
    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And created the example tree like this:

```
    Node<Character> root;
    root = new Node<>('A');
    root.left = new Node<>('B');
    root.left.left = new Node<>('C');
    root.left.left.left = new Node<>('D');
    root.right = new Node<>('P');
    root.right.right = new Node<>('Q');
```

The difference in the output from the correct result is small for 4 levels,
but it gets much worse if you stack more nodes to the left and to the right branches.

#### Alternative implementation

Here's a recursive implementation that works correctly,
and it also happens to be a lot simpler:

```
<T> void printLevelOrder(Node<T> root) {
    if (root != null) {
        printLevelOrder(Arrays.asList(root));
    }
}

<T> void printLevelOrder(List<Node<T>> level) {
    List<Node<T>> nextLevel = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Node<T> node : level) {
        System.out.println(node.data);
        if (node.left != null) {
            nextLevel.add(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            nextLevel.add(node.right);
        }
    }
    if (!nextLevel.isEmpty()) {
        printLevelOrder(nextLevel);
    }
}
```

#### Other coding style issues

Don't check boolean expressions like this:

> ```
> while(stack.isEmpty() == false) {
> ```

"Empty equals false" is really a confusing way to say "not empty"

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
```

---

Starting from Java 7, you don't need to specify type parameters like this:

> ```
> Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
> ```

You can use the diamond `<>` operator and the compiler can figure out what to do:

```
Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
```

Comment: Yep, mine is not working as it keeps going 'left' after level 3, then to 'right'. Thanks!

Comment: I could re-work your implementation for zigzag level order traversal too!

Answer (score 4):

A few things that catch my eye, just skimming over your code:

1. Unconventional method names:

   Java method names are supposed to be named strictly in `camelCase`. You're using some bastardized camel-snake-pascal-case which is something I'd expect when mixing together PHP, Python and C++... *~shivers*
2. Use of outdated API:

   Stack is a class in Java retroactively added to the Collections API, but it should've been officially deprecated since Java 1.5. It's been officially replaced by [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which is an interface that supports all stack-operations, see also [Stack's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

   > A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
   >   provided by the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations
3. Returning a Collection from a method which begins with `print`

   A method name should not lie. For a method named `print...` I'd expect to give something to be printed and some output channel (e.g. BufferedOutputWriter) with no return value. Instead you should name it something like `traverseLevelOrder`.
4. Overcomplicated helper method:

   For a recursive traversal it's definitely not necessary to have a method that takes two nodes. Instead of relying on the caller to maintain the Stack you have, you may want to give the `Stack` (or better the Deque) into the recursive traversal for a level-order traversal. Also it's a significant difference whether you only want to traverse the nodes or also keep the traversal results in memory...
5. General recursive approach:

   It might be a better option to actually do the level-order traversal with an "iterative" approach, by maintaining the nodes you still have to traverse in a queue that builds up by level and just process them back again. Following code should give you an idea:

   ```
   void traverse(Node node) {
       Queue<Node> traversalQueue = new LinkedList<>();
       traversalQueue.add(node);
       while (!traversalQueue.isEmpty()) {
           // add nodes to queue by level
           // and pop the current:
           traversalQueue.add(node.left); // null-checks omitted
           traversalQueue.add(node.right);
           // use node.data
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is… interesting code.  Breadth-first traversals are normally done using a queue.  It seems that you are aware of that, since you wrote `Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>(); queue.add(root2);` — but then you never used `queue` again after that.  Instead, you use a lot of `Stack<Node>` data structures, with items stored in reverse order so that when you `pop()` them in this loop…

> ```
> while(stack.isEmpty() == false) {
>     Node node = stack.pop();
>     System.out.println(node.data);
> }
> ```

the nodes will be "de-queued" in the desired order.

Furthermore, those aren't really stacks.  Stacks traditionally support operations push, pop, and peek, with bookkeeping operations size and isEmpty.  When you call `stack.addAll(…)`, that's taking advantage of Java's poorly designed `java.util.Stack` implementation which mistakenly inherits from `java.util.Vector`.  The `.addAll()` method shouldn't really be available in a proper stack.

I recommend starting over, using no stacks and only the `queue`.